# Is there a way to deploy SQL Server Reporting Services without SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, reporting-services

I'm currently working on an application that runs a small SQLite DB, but I want to use `.RDLC` for reporting.

I generate the reports over my view models, the idea was for them to be decoupled from the DB, but now I run into this snag that I have to install SQL Server in order to use the reporting framework.

I wouldn't want to require my clients to install SQL Server on their machines just to be able to generate reports. They won't be happy about that. And I don't want to redesign my reporting component either(I have something from a previous project which used SQL Server and that works very well. I want to reuse it)

Is there a way to deploy the Reporting framework on the target machine without SQL Server?

Ideally I would like to just just copy the needed libraries in my application's installation folder, under OTS, but I don't really know which libraries to copy and what I can leave out or even if it's going to work this way.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Ummm....the data for the reports has to come from....sql server. How would you propose storing the data without sql server?

Comment: The ssrs portion of sql server runs within the context of sql server, which is generally a server side installation. I am afraid there is no BI or analytic processing for local sql lite installs.

Comment: @Sean Lange I have a solution for that.
The data does not come directly from the DB, but is a collection that is added problematically to the report. 
It's basically a collection of view models.

Comment: I think you were missing my point. SSRS is an installed application just like Office or any other application. When you don't have that application installed you can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we ended up doing is installing two nuget packages.

Microsoft.ReportViewer.Windows and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

This will allow us to use the reporting framework without deploying SQL server on our target machines.

Answer (score 0):

No.   SSRS will only work on a machine with SQL Server installed on it.

Same with SSAS and SSIS.

Comment: You can actually install all of those components standalone without needing SQL Server (the database server) installed on the same machine

Comment: True that you don't need the database engine, but you do need a licensed SQL Server installation thingy.